# Perl Template Toolkit passing to Jquery Tools overlay?

Tags: perl, jquery-tools, template-toolkit

I am using Template::Toolkit to build my pages. I have a list of links on a page that each trigger an overlay using Jquery Tools. I want to pass some CGI variables to it but it is acting strange. My code in Template is:

```
[% FOREACH dvd IN dvd_chart %]

<div class="thumbnail">
<a href="popup.pl?overview=[% dvd.overview %]" rel="#overlay" style="text-decoration:none"><img  src="[% dvd.thumbnail %]" /></a>
<br />

</div>
[% END %]
```

The problem is that overview doesn't make it to the overlay. In fact the overlay appears blank. If I change the Template variable for a string the string does appear in the template. Does anyone know if there is some escaping that needs to be done to pass the Template variable? BTW, the [% dvd.overview %] variable is valid as I can dump it to screen and see the string.

Comment: Can you add an example overview value?  It might be that there's something that does need escaping.

Comment: @martinclayton: thanks for that, you did enough to make me try escaping the overview before putting into the hash, it now passes correctly to the popup! - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Template toolkit has built-in filters([specifically html and html_entity](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Filters.html#section_html)) for this situation. They are a good idea to use here in particular, because even if unescaped content rendered correctly, as you mentioned these are CGI variables passed from the client. Rendering unescaped client-supplied data is dangerous.

Here's a sample of how you might appropriately escape, without cluttering up your business logic with superfluous code. Just add `| html` to variable output.

```
[% FOREACH dvd IN dvd_chart %]

<div class="thumbnail">
<a href="popup.pl?overview=[% dvd.overview | html %]" rel="#overlay" style="text-decoration:none"><img  src="[% dvd.thumbnail |html %]" /></a>
<br />

</div>
[% END %]
```